# I have charset problem. Result of Process looks corrupt

Tags: php, laravel, process, exec

I'm waiting for the code that I wrote in python using Laravel Process () to return my sentence to cleared. But the sentence does not return properly.

```
 $text=$this->argument('text');
    $process=new Process("C:/Users/ertan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe ".public_path()."\script\web.py ".'"'.$text.'"'."");
    $process->run();

    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    $result=$process->getOutput();
    echo $result;
```

Text:"mayıs günü geleceğini umut ediyorum sakın"

Result:

```
g�n� gelece�ini umut ediyorum sak�n
```

Git bash and CMD working properly
Phpstorm and Pycharm working properly

How can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like a UTF-8 / ASCII mismatch. Text is ASCII  (maybe LATIN-1),, but page coding is UTF-8.